# How to set selected networks in StorageAccount via ARM Template

Tags: azure, arm, azure-storage, vnet

I have the following ARM template to generate an storage account and add existing virtual networks:

```
   {
      "name": "test0deep0123",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "location": "West Europe",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {
        "firewallState": "Enabled",
        "virtualNetworkRules": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnetId": "subnetid"
            },
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnetId": "subnetId"
            },
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnetId": "subnetid"
            },
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnetId": "subnetid"
            },
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnetId": "subnetid"
            },
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnetId": subnetid"
            },
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnetId": "subnetid"
            },
            "name": "name"
          }

        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "virtualNetworkRules": [
            {
              "id": "id",
              "action": "Allow",
              "state": "succeeded"
            },
            {
              "id": "id",
              "action": "Allow",
              "state": "succeeded"
            }
          ],
          "ipRules": [],
          "defaultAction": "Allow"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": false,
        "encryption": {
          "services": {
            "file": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "blob": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
        },
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      }
    }
```

I can successfully  deploy this template in the resource group but after controlling  “Firewall and virtual networks” I see, that allows access from is set to all networks, although under the selected networks I can see added Virtual Networks
[image]

what should I do have "selected networks" checked?

Comment: Do you have any question on my reply?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It helps me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that if you set the `virtualNetworkRules` to `allow` then the  `defaultAction` need to set to `Deny`, so you will whitelist the selected virtual networks in the firewall of the storage account.

In this case, you could select your existing virtual network (which [enable the storage account service endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-restrict-network-access-to-resources#enable-a-service-endpoint)) ID to the paragraph `networkAcls` and change the  `"defaultAction": "Deny"`. Also, `virtualNetworkRules` belongs to the`networkAcls` not the properties of the storage account.

This following template could work on my side.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
            "virtualNetworks_vnet1": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet",
            "type": "string"
        },
            "virtualNetworks_vnet2": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/mytestvnet1",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "name": "test0deep01234",
            "location": "Central US",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [
                        {
                            "id": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet1'), '/subnets/default')]",
                            "action": "Allow"

                        },
                         {
                            "id": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet2'), '/subnets/default')]",
                            "action": "Allow"

                        }
                    ],
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "defaultAction": "Deny"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": false,
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                },
                "accessTier": "Hot"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Ref: [Microsoft.Storage storageAccounts template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2018-11-01/storageaccounts)

Comment: this is not what the person is asking at all

Comment: @4c74356b41 edit to make it clear and the person could understand me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the property `publicNetworkAccess` and set it to `Disabled`

Hope this helps?